# Deploying a file in Artifactory's Web GUI generates an '<filename> undefined' error

Tags: artifactory

I am using Artifactory Professional, version 5.6.0 rev 50600900

When I try to deploy a file through the Artifactory web UI, I'm getting an error:  `'<filename> is undefined'`  in a red popup box.

When I look in the system log, I see:

```
2018-05-15 08:25:41,037 [http-nio-8081-exec-123] [ERROR] (o.a.r.c.e.GlobalExceptionMapper:48) - Permission denied
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

The time corresponds to the time I tried the deploy

Uploads using a curl command or via the Artifactory plugin in Jenkins work without any problems.

I am an administrator on Artifactory. other users with Delete/Overwrite, Deploy/Cache, Annotate and Read also are not able to upload to repos via the web UI.

I get the undefined error with all files i try to deploy, large or small. this error occurs for users on windows, mac os and linux.

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you provide all the relevant logs from the Artifactory logs (artifactory.log and request.log)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an file system permissions issue. Make sure that the OS user running Artifactory has write permissions to `<ARTIFACTORY_HOME>/data/tmp`.
The artifacts uploaded from the UI are temporally saved under this folder.

Comment: thanks.  we found this late friday and IT fixed the permissions issue. we verified that this did fix the problem.